# Why does Vue not cache method results?

Tags: vue.js

Vue has the concept of Computed Properties. They only get re-evaluated when one of their dependency changes. An example:

```
computed: {
  foo() {
    return this.bar + this.baz;
  }
}
```

```
<div>{{ foo }}</div>
```

This Computed Property only gets re-evaluated when `this.bar` or `this.baz` change. Which works because of how Vue utilizes Proxy objects for change detection.

Now take a look at methods:

```
methods: {
  foo() {
    return this.bar + this.baz;
  }
}
```

```
<div>{{ foo() }}</div>
```

This method will be called on every single re-render. Which is pretty bad for the performance of the application.

My question: Why doesn't Vue also cache the results of method calls in the template? From a technical point of view, I see no difference between Computed Properties and Methods. So it should be possible to just utilize the same reactivity mechanisms as used for Computed Properties. Is there any use case for actually re-evaluating methods on every render cycle?

Comment: if they made both the same so there is no need to both of them, the difference is the methods accept arguments but the computes property don't

Comment: OK then my follow-up question now is: Why don't Computed Properties accept parameters? :D For Change Detection, you would only have to check whether any of the parameters has changed. So from a technical point of view, I don't understand why you would not provide this functionality.

Comment: They don't accept parameters because they are... properties? A getter doesn't accept a parameter. This conforms to JS getters. From tech point of view, the next question for parametrized cache would be, how much params need to be stored, and how this will affect memory consumption. There's no good answer for this, and this is the reason why this isn't handled by the framework. This is a problem that you'll have to deal with when using third-party memoization. It's supposed to drop values from cache at some point, or it will eat up RAM.

Comment: I think I am getting your point. You would essentially have to keep all copies of the parameters at every point in the template where a method invocation takes place. Which would probably take up quite a lot of RAM. However, when optimized properly, you could maybe just have a worst-case memory usage of O(n), with n being the size of the Component state itself. Which makes me wonder if I am missing something :D

Comment: Both params and results need to be kept, and there can be multiple params. A param can be anything and isn't limited to component state, so cache size for long-running component instance goes to infinity. AFAIK Vue computeds have semantic guarantee that they won't be called again without a reason, so dropping something from cache on framework level to reduce RAM consumption is not an option, this should be user-controlled, with LRU cache or else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious difference between computed properties and method results is that methods shouldn't necessary involve component instance exclusively, so they shouldn't cache results.

If a value is not parametrized, it can be extracted to a computed on per need basis:

```
computed: {
  foobaz() {
    return this.bar + this.baz;
  }
},
methods: {
  foobazRandom() {
    return this.foobaz + Math.random();
  }
}
```

If method result needs to be cached, this needs to be explicitly handled by a developer, most likely with memoization.

Comment: The "issue" with your `Math.random()` example is that Vue will re-evaluate this method only when a new render cycle gets triggered. (i.e. Vue doesn't use Polling) So developers shouldn't expect this being executed every second (or so) anyways. Thus, Vue could also just say "hey, let's cache the result until one dependency of the method changes".

Comment: A method isn't necessarily supposed to be called in view. A lot of times it's called by other methods. *Vue could also just say* - yes, it could, but this would be wrong because you can force this behaviour yourself if it doesn't exist, but you can't cancel this behaviour if it does. The dependency in this case will be a parameter, which can have infinite values, and this will cause cache to grow infinitely. Also, in composition API there's no difference between methods and just functions (`data` functions in Vue 2), so special treatment for `methods` doesn't make sense.

Comment: FWIW, I ran into the issue you describe with computeds inside v-for. Most times the solution is to extract a part that requires computereds to be parametrized into a different component and control caching with `key`.

Comment: OK so essentially to have some kind of "cached" method result, I would have the option to either: 1. Extract the parts into a separate component or 2. Implement Memoization and then actually call the respective method in the template. Did I understand this correctly?

Comment: Yes. Most times you want to make the cache specific to the component, so memoized method should likely be added to `data` and fine-tune cache according to your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanations! I will mark your answer as the accepted one, since our conversation answered everything I needed :-)